# Eclipse standard output/error synchronization

Tags: java, eclipse

Im running some code and expecting to get a specific message sent to Systen.err to come out at one point, but for some reason its coming out at another point. Here is the code -

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {       
        System.out.println("File 1:");      
        for (NormalizedEntity ne : theSolution.entities.values()){
            System.out.println(ne);
        }

        System.out.println("\nFile 2:");
        for (NormalizedEntity ne : theSubmission.entities.values()){
            System.out.println(ne);
        }
        System.out.println(check());
    }

    static String check() {
        StringBuilder resultString = new StringBuilder();

        System.out.println("\nstarting check");
        for (NormalizedEntity solutionEntity : theSolution.entities.values()){
            NormalizedEntity submissionEntity = theSubmission.entities.get(solutionEntity.name);

            if(solutionEntity instanceof NormalizedClass){
                if(!(submissionEntity instanceof NormalizedClass)){
                    System.err.println("***WARNING: solutionEntity " + solutionEntity + "is a class but submissionEntity " + submissionEntity + " is not");//<---This line should be second to last
                    resultString.append("Expected " + submissionEntity + " to be a class called " + solutionEntity);
                }               
            }   

            //System.out.println("Found: " + ne + " in both");
        }
        return resultString.toString();
    }
```

And here is the output -

```
***WARNING: solutionEntity Class C {x=private int x, y=private int y} {C=C{1thParam=int, 2thParam=int}} {getX=int getX{}}is a class but submissionEntity null is not <--------- THIS LINE SHOULD BE AT THE END
File 1:
Class C {x=private int x, y=private int y} {C=C{1thParam=int, 2thParam=int}} {getX=int getX{}}
Class SubC {z=private int z} {} {}
C c
double d
int f{}
int i
SubC subC

File 2:
Class D {x=private int x, y=private int y} {D=D{1thParam=int, 2thParam=int}} {getX=int getX{}}
Class SubC {z=private int z} {} {}
D c
double d
int f{}
int i
SubC subC

starting check
Expected null to be a class called Class C {x=private int x, y=private int y} {C=C{1thParam=int, 2thParam=int}} {getX=int getX{}}
```

Now based on the code the first line of output should be the second to last line. However, when I run this in eclipse it comes out as the first line. Why is this? I also noticed that if I change the `System.err` to `System.out` it comes out as expected. So it seems like Eclipse first collects all the error output and then deals with the standard output?

Comment: `err` takes precedence and immediately gets printed out. I've had cases where a stack trace has been printed in the middle of a line.

Answer (score 1):

Writing to two different streams is inherently prone to out of order display, however, System.out.println should auto-flush with each call, meaning that the situation you are seeing should not be possible, or at worst should be able to be mitigated with synchronization.

Unfortunately, a bug in eclipse is actually preventing this from working correctly and leading to the out of order lines you are seeing:  [Synchronisation problem between System.out and System.err in the console](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=32205)

You may want to consider using a logging framework such as logback (+ SLF4J if desired) to allow you to log different levels of messages while maintaining a consistent ordering.